# How to choose default time value in a select box with ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, jquery-selectbox

I have a form with select boxes to choose a business' working hours. I want to choose 9:00 am as the default value for the first box, and 5:00 pm as the default value for the second box.

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waleedasif322/9178azcm/4/)

For example, I have

```
<select ng-options="hour as (hour | date: 'shortTime') for hour in hours"
  ng-model="start_time" ng-change="update(start_time, $index, 1)">
```

If in my app.js I set `$scope.start_time` equal to a Date object initialized to the current date and time as 9:00 am, the default value is chosen as the last value in the select box instead. Since I am using a date filter to display the time in the select box in the 'shortTime' format, is that the reason why the default value is not being shown correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the model `start_time` right, for example in your controller!

```
<select ng-options="hour as (hour | date: 'shortTime') for hour in hours track by hour"
        ng-model="start_time" ng-change="update(start_time, $index, 1)">

$scope.start_time = new Date(); // set default date in controller
```

Using the latest angular version and `track by hour` solves the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/j8xu1h2h/

Comment: Hey, I actually added the $scope.start_time in the JSfiddle, see it now. Forgot to add it before

Comment: niceee. How did you know that the new version of angular supported that?

Comment: honestly it was just a guess, but I think I read it in the changelog (at bug fixes) at some point - I am not exactly sure what angular version though ;)