# Angular Empty option (Dynamic input)

Tags: angularjs

Been searching all over Stackoverflow and there is loads of tips on how to remove the 'dreaded' empty (undefined) options element in a select dropdown. However I have yet to find an answer for when my code looks like this:

--VIEW--

```
<form class="simple-mods">
<fieldset ng-repeat="modifier in modifiers">
    <label for="{{ modifier.id }}">{{ modifier.title }}</label>
        <select name="" id="{{ modifier.id }}"  ng-model="mods[modifier.id]" name="modifier[{{ modifier.id }}]" ng-mod="{{ modifier.title }}">
           <option value="{{ variation.id }}" ng-repeat="variation in modifier.variations">{{ variation.title }}</option>
        </select>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <button ng-click="addCart()" ng-if="!addStatus" class="btn btn-success"  translate>Add to cart</button>
    <button ng-if="addStatus" class="btn btn-warning" ng-bind-html="addStatus">{{ addStatus }}</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

-- CONTROLLER --

```
.controller('ProductCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, moltin, $timeout, product) {

var productId  = product.id,
    qty = 1,
    mods = {};

$scope.product = product;
$scope.addStatus = null;
$scope.modifiers = product.modifiers;

});
```

If any one can help I would be very grateful.

@BETTY it doesnt seem to work. I have attached 2 screenshots

[Screen shot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIHql.png)

[Screen shot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LCXV.png) (Value is now a string)

@betty

```
<fieldset ng-repeat="modifier in modifiers" ng-init="mod[modifier.id] = modifier.variations[0].id">
    <label for="{{ modifier.id }}">{{ modifier.title }}</label>
        <select id="{{ modifier.id }}" ng-model="mods[modifier.id]" ng-options="variation.id as variation.title for variation in modifier.variations">
            <option></option>
        </select>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean up modifier.variations in your controller, deleting undefined elements from `modifier.variations`

```
$scope.modifier.variations = $scope.modifier.variations.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined });
```

You need to inject `$scope` in your controller.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. But thank you for responding so quickly

Comment: @Richy I added another way, try it.

Comment: Oh man, I am really struggling with this. I am getting modifier is not defined. My controller code is

    .controller('ProductCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, moltin, $timeout, product) {

    var productId  = product.id,
        qty = 1,
        mod = {};

   $scope.product = product;
   $scope.addStatus = null;
    $scope.modifiers = product.modifiers;

Comment: @Richy Oh my bad I forgot to use $scope, $ , I update it.

Comment: Levi, I really appreciate you helping me out here, but Im still getting modifier is not defined. Just cant get my head around it.

Comment: @Richy can u post u whole controller code on your answer, also your view plz

Comment: Can you help me @levi ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ng-model right (`=> mods[modifier.id]`), either by using `ng-init` or setting it in the controller..

This solution uses `ng-init` which sets the default value to the first variation ID. I also removed everything you don't need and used `ng-options` (reduces some HTML ;)).

```
<fieldset ng-repeat="modifier in modifiers" ng-init="mods[modifier.id]=modifier.variations[0].id">
  <label for="{{ modifier.id }}">{{ modifier.title }}</label>
  <select id="{{ modifier.id }}" ng-model="mods[modifier.id]" ng-options="variation.id as variation.title for variation in modifier.variations">
    <option></option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

I also recommend adding an empty option-tag, here is why: [ng-model is getting wrong value from dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999394/ng-model-is-getting-wrong-value-from-dropdown/32999467#32999467)

AND you need `$scope.mods = {};` in the controller instead of `var mods = {};` because you are using `mods` in the HTML!

Maybe you also need to use `track by variation.id` so that the selected value can be checked right (ng-model and option value). I answered a similar question and `track by` was the answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32999399/595152 ;)

Comment: Betty had some problems with this. I have responded with the problems in the original post above

Comment: '<fieldset ng-repeat="modifier in modifiers" ng-init="mod[modifier.id] = modifier.variations[0].id">
      <label for="{{ modifier.id }}">{{ modifier.title }}</label>
      <select id="{{ modifier.id }}" ng-model="mods[modifier.id]" ng-options="variation.id as variation.title for variation in modifier.variations">
        <option></option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>'

Comment: ah you need `$scope.mods = {};` in the controller instead of `var mods = {};`  because you are using `mods` in the HTML!

Comment: Hmmm still not working.. also in Options my value now looks likes this

value="string:1102120689898357713" 

It should be

value="1102120689898357713"

PLEASE NOTE there is inconsistencies above with the 'mod' and 'mods'. This has been resolved in my working copy :)

Comment: that's strange what is `variation.id` ?  `string:1102120689898357713`  or just `1102120689898357713` . ... can you make an jsfiddle?

Comment: `ng-init="mods[modifier.id]=....` and `ng-model="mods[modifier.id]"`  needs to be the same

Comment: Not sure i can make a fiddle as my data is coming from an API. VARIATION.ID should be just  1102120689898357713

Comment: just fake it in your controller by defining `$scope.modifiers = [{..}]` just copy the response from your API

Comment: if I do <options value="{{ variation.id }}"> then I get <options value="1102120689898357713"> which is correct

Comment: Hey betty, I have tried creating a fiddle, but the response from my api is pretty complex. Basically i am using Moltin which is a API for creating ecommerce websites. Think Im going to hide under a rock for a couple of days :(

Comment: You just need to copy the JSON from your api response, and paste it in your controller instead of `= product.modifiers` you will write `= {...}`! .. one other thing: It is fine that angular adds a "string:..." and it is just an angular thing!  For your solution, maybe you should read this: http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/

Comment: @Richy I've updated my answer, maybe this is the solution!